# Web API 2.2 OData V4 not recognizing primary key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

In Web API 2.2 WebApiConfig.cs:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder=new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers")
```

Customer entity is generated by the entity data model wizard.  "EF Designer from database"
When i try to load the entity it returns error "Customer entity has no key"

Even though the CSDL file specifies the primary key and it works with Web API actions

```
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="CustomerID">
</Key>
...
```

The workaround has been to manually add  the [Key] annotation attribute in the model.

QUESTION: Is this a bug?  How can I resolve this issue, without having to manually edit anything to specify the primary key for each entity?

Answer (score 0):

In Your CSDL example you are not closing the PropertyRef tag with "/>". This XML syntax error could make to ignore the Customer Key.

```
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="CustomerID" />
</Key>
...
```